# SVG FontAwesome does not take CSS effect

Tags: css, svg

I tried to add CSS style to my fontawesome svg but it does not take effect.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<section id="about">
<div class="container">
<ul>
<li>
<i class="fas fa-shipping-fast"></i>
<h3>Free Delivery</h3>
<p class="desc">text text text</p>
</li>
<li>
<i class="far fa-clock"></i>
<h3>Instant Delivery</h3>
<p class="desc">text text text</p>
</li>
<li class="support">
<i class="fas fa-phone-square"></i>
<h3>24/d/w Support</h3>
<p class="desc">text text text</p>
</li>
<li class="customers">
<i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
<h3>Customer Satisfaction</h3>
<p class="desc">text text text</p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</section>
```

And here is CSS code:

```
#about svg {
font-size: 50px;
float: right;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 7px;
}
```

The svgs must have size 50px and right float but as you see in my screenshot its not working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ1Rf.jpg)

Comment: svg don't support font-size .. you need use the classes provided by font-awesome to increase the size

Comment: @TemaniAfif to my surprize it seems to be working https://jsfiddle.net/y3rjaLzh/ ( tested in FF also ) . so it might be some `height/width` constraints causing this.

Comment: @MihaiT hmm, they are using 1em unit for the width which is based on font-size that's why. It works in this case for font awesome but not in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not use the right selector i believe :

```css
#about i {
font-size: 50px;
float: right;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section id="about">
<div class="container">
<ul>
<li>
<i class="fas fa-shipping-fast"></i>
<h3>Free Delivery</h3>
<p class="desc">text text text</p>
</li>
<li>
<i class="far fa-clock"></i>
<h3>Instant Delivery</h3>
<p class="desc">text text text</p>
</li>
<li class="support">
<i class="fas fa-phone-square"></i>
<h3>24/d/w Support</h3>
<p class="desc">text text text</p>
</li>
<li class="customers">
<i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
<h3>Customer Satisfaction</h3>
<p class="desc">text text text</p>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</section>
```